# jsf make ui:param result static

Tags: jsf, user-interface, parameters, include, el

I am using templating and pass some values by  to use them in the template:

```
<ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{showEntriesBean.entries}" id="repeatId">
    <ui:include src="/templates/entryTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="prePath" value="/" />
        <ui:param name="allowedToSee" value="#{bean.calcRandom(0, 10)}" />
    </ui:include>
    <br />
</ui:repeat>
```

I found out, that everytime I use the "allowedToSee" variable in my entryTemplate.xhtml, it recalculates its value.

Is there any way to pass the result of calcRandom in a static way? So it is ONCE calculated (when the allowedToSee value is calculated) and performs like a final number? I don't want it to be calculated everytime #{allowedToSee} is used

Comment: Which JSF version are you using?

Comment: JSF 2.0 myfaces impl.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to be held, you should held it somewhere.

What I would do:

1) Create a `List<Integer>` property.

2) When the values of the `entries` properties are set, call a method (`preRenderEvent`? `@PostConstruct?`) that introduces in your list as many items as there are in `entries`.

3) Consult that list using the `varStatus` attribute of `ui:repeat`

Little more of less, like:

```
<ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{showEntriesBean.entries}" id="repeatId" varStatus="status">
  <ui:include src="/templates/entryTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="prePath" value="/" />
    <ui:param name="allowedToSee" value="#{bean.getPrecalculedRandomAt(status.index)}" />
  </ui:include>
  <br />
</ui:repeat>
```

More on the `varStatus` attribute: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html

Comment: so this is expected behaviour